# SQL IF function inside of ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL code that is supposed to get a list of IDs with a Name column and simply swap IDs of adjacent names in pairs down the list.

NOTE: It works correctly, this post is mainly about how it works

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() id, student
FROM seat
ORDER BY IF(MOD(id, 2) = 0, id-1, id+1)
```

My confusion lies in the `ORDER BY` clause at the bottom, from my understanding the `IF()` function should return either `id-1` or `id+1` depending on how `MOD(id, 2) = 0` gets evaluated. However instead the code applies the `id-1` or `id+1` calculation to the returned `id` value instead of returning one of the 2 calculations directly to the `ORDER BY` clause. Shouldn't the changes to the `id` column be applied somewhere else, and the `ORDER BY` should then be given `id` only to determine the order? Or am I misunderstanding how the `IF()` function returns things?

Example of table:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike |
| 2 | Bob |
| 3 | Joe |
| 4 | Kevin |
| 5 | James |

Example of what I want, swapping adjacent rows. If the table has an odd number of entries, the last stays the same instead of being swapped

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Mike |
| 3 | Kevin |
| 4 | Joe |
| 5 | James |

Comment: It should return `id-1` or `id+1` because those are the calcs in expression, not `id-1` or `id-2`. If you want to see the calculation then need a calculated field in the SELECT clause as well. If you want to sort by ID then don't do any calc in ORDER BY. Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables.

Comment: Sorry about that, that was a typo. I updated the post with more information. My understanding was that the `IF()` statement would return the result of the expression with id-1 or id+1 and feed that directly into the `ORDER BY`, i.e. if it was the 4th entry then the last line would become `ORDER BY id-1`

Comment: Records are sorted by the value calculated in ORDER BY clause. Not sure what else you would expect. Unfortunately, I can't test your SQL because only have Access available.

Comment: That's where I get confused, wouldn't then the last `ORDER BY` line, depending on value of the rows, alternate between `ORDER BY id+1` and `ORDER BY id-1`? Why does this alter what gets printed? For example if id was `3`, wouldn't the last line be `ORDER BY 3+1`? Why would it actually print out that value of 4 in the `id` column if it's only in the `ORDER BY` clause? My SQL is extremely rusty so this is throwing me off

Comment: The query in the original post works and gives the desired output, which (as far as I can tell) means it's showing the newly calculated results right? I can't really comprehend why it would show these new values in `id` in the output table if this calculation is only within the `ORDER BY` and not `SELECT`

Comment: Well, that is the case. Your query is showing value calculated by RowNumber(), not value from ID or the If(). Include If() calc as a calculated field in SELECT and you will see what I mean. The number 5 should not be a result from the If() for the sample given. Could also include ID as a separate field in the SELECT and compare all three values.

Comment: So does that mean if the last line evaluated to `ORDER BY 4` (from `ORDER BY 3+1`) like if  the RowNumber() gave us `3` originally, that it would place that data in the 4th row?

Comment: RowNumber() would return 4 but the ID would still be 3 because that's what is in table field. However, the fifth row will show RowNumber of 5 but the If() calc is 6. This assumes ID is always increasing and there are no gaps in sequence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228066/discussion-between-june7-and-user3491700).

Answer (score 0):

This query works:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() id, IFNULL((
      SELECT IFNULL(s2.student, s.student)
      FROM seat s2
      WHERE s2.id = (CASE WHEN MOD(s.id, 2) = 0 THEN s.id-1 ELSE s.id+1 END)
  ), s.student) as student
FROM seat s
ORDER BY s.id;
```

->

```
id  student
1   Bob
2   Mike
3   Kevin
4   Joe
5   James
```

Comment: CASE doesn't really do anything different than If().